# MonoTouch OR Sencha Touch?

Tags: android, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, sencha-touch

There is no doubt that MonoTouch is one of the great cross-compiler(s). Similarly, SenchaTouch is one of the great HTML 5 Web App Kit.

I know a little about both of them however i made a very small application using MonoTouch for iPad, certainly MonoTouch (and particularly with supporting XCode) is awesome. But i did not tried SenchaTouch

The advantage of using MonoTouch is that you can write c#; consequently i really enjoy it owing to the fact that i am a c# developer; In contrast a disadvantage of SenchaTouch for me is Java language and i really did not find any IDE like visual studio or xcode to Drag&Drop UI(s) and it generate the Xml Code

Many are in this view that on account of the fact that MonoTouch is a Cross-Compiler; Consequently the applications developed by MonoTouch is not as fast as others like SenchaTouch .

I am really looking for a good advise from you,
Your advise is welcome here.

Regards,
S. Peyman Mortazavi

Comment: SenchaTouch is all about Javascript but not Java. I hate Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Monotouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) is not a cross-compiler, and even if it were that alone would not cause a performance penalty.

Monotouch is a .Net compatible runtime that [runs on iOS embedded](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aRuntime#Embedded_systems) within a normal c/obj-c program. It includes bindings for more or less the same things you can do from normal iOS apps. Monotouch apps are AOT compiled rather than JIT compiled so in most cases they run just as fast as "normal apps"

The fact that [SenchaTouch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) is a javascript framework suggests to me that you will be running mainly interpretted code. I'm sure the Sencha people have done a good job but I would be suprised if it were faster than mono. Looking at Sencha, one advantage is that you can write for android, blackberry and iOS. You can share much of your code between MonoTouch and [Mono for Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid), you need two licenses and can't share everything.

Comment: dear IanNorton, Thanks for your reply. I did not know that, for my case MonoTouch is better and there is only one thing left! can i use Mono technology (MonoTouch, MonoDroid, ...) to develop web apps? However if its impossible too i use Mono for app developing and SenchaTouch for web developing. I say again, thanks !

Comment: Peyman, you need to split your code along the lines of your business logic and your presentation layer.   Then you could implement a new presentation UI for each platform: iOS with MonoTouch, Android with MonoDroid and ASP.NET for the web.

Comment: @PeymanMortazavi yes, you can share a lot with iOS, Android, .Net/Mono Desktop and ASP.Net and as Miguel says, you need to split things up, this is more than just needed for the Mono ecosystem, it is a good idea in general and makes testing things much easier.

Comment: you are right, I better do this. ASP.NET MCV 4.0 for web based applications, Mono Technology for developing applications for iOS and Android. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that with the upcoming Windows Phone, you will be able to support this platform as well if you use C# - you will be able to re-use you libraries the contain the shared code.